# Programmatically calling main(int argc, char **argv) in C

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing, program-entry-point

Let's say I have a file `test.c` which accepts a text file and starts as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

I will typically compile the file and execute the binary as follows: `./test input.txt`.

Now, I wish to call the `main` function programmatically in another function in the same file. How should I proceed?

Comment: Why do you want to call the `main` function? That's almost certainly the wrong way to achieve whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't do it ! Whatever you want to do should be a separate vunction called from main() and anywhere else you want to call it from...

Comment: Is it an option for you to create a separate program (with its own `main()`)  which calls this one? Or maybe just a script/batch?

Comment: Note that you are not permitted to call [`main()` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18721336/15168) at all — but it is legitimate to call it in C, though it is unorthodox to do so except in programming contests such as the IOCCC (International Obfuscated C Code Contest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

void func()
{
    char *argv[] = { "./test", "another.txt", NULL };
    main(2, argv);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        printf("Processing %s...\n", argv[1]);
    }

    /* ... */

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

This should output something like:

```
Processing input.txt...
Processing another.txt...
```

Beware of endless recursion!

Comment: I was especially looking on how to pass the second argument for which you provided a clear example. Thanks!